# Autofac and Web API self host

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, self-hosting

I get the error:

> "The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext
>   is not available."

if I try to setup my web api.

HttpContext is not available in System.Web.Http.SelfHost but is there an alternative?

Example with my AuthenticationHandler:

```
    public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private const string m_AuthenticationScheme = "Basic";
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeader = request.Headers.Authorization; //get the authorization header

            if (authenticationHeader != null && authenticationHeader.Scheme == m_AuthenticationScheme) 
            {
                Credentials credentials = authenticationHeader.ParseAuthenticationHeader();

                if (credentials != null)
                {   
                    IMyClass procadCredentials = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyClass>(); //thows the InvalidOperationException if I use self-hosting
//tried: "Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyClass>();" too.
```

I got the InvalidOperationException with the message:

> The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext
>   is not available.

IMyClass is registeres in global.asax like this:

```
m_builder.Register<IMyClass>((c, p) =>
            {
//...
//return ...
}
```

While IIS-Hosting, it works fine, but using self-hosting, IoC with AutoFac fails.

Comment: Please could you provide more code?

Comment: [Lifetime scope](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope#Per_Matching_Lifetime_Scope).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Autofac's MVC integration package with Web API, while you should really be using `Autofac.WebApi` http://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi

You can read more about it here - http://alexmg.com/post/2012/09/01/New-features-in-the-Autofac-MVC-4-and-Web-API-(Beta)-Integrations.aspx

Comment: I use both. But The WebApi DependencyResolver doesnt work too